Why is the actual library used after I mock it with Jest?
There's many similar questions to this, but I can't find any that solve my issue.
I'm using jest.mock to mock the Plaid library like this:
jest.mock('plaid', () => ({
  Configuration: jest.fn(),
  PlaidApi: jest.fn(() => ({
    linkTokenCreate: jest.fn(),
    itemPublicTokenExchange: jest.fn(),
    transactionsSync: jest.fn(),
  })),
  PlaidEnvironments: {
    sandbox: 'https://sandbox.plaid.com',
  },
}))

Then initialize it like this:
describe('Plaid', () => {
  let plaid: Plaid
  let plaidApiMock: jest.Mocked<PlaidApi>

  beforeAll(() => {
    plaidApiMock = new PlaidApi({} as Configuration) as jest.Mocked<PlaidApi>
    plaid = new Plaid()
  })

// ... the rest of the tests

Where Plaid is my wrapper class that I'm testing. But within the test, both the wrapper class and the test still use the real library PlaidApi. This is exactly the method I use to mock libraries in other tests and it works, so I'm really lost here.
I found one potential solution, it was to change my mock code to this:
jest.mock('plaid', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: {
    Configuration: jest.fn(),
    PlaidApi: jest.fn(() => ({
      linkTokenCreate: jest.fn(),
      itemPublicTokenExchange: jest.fn(),
      transactionsSync: jest.fn(),
    })),
    PlaidEnvironments: {
      sandbox: 'https://sandbox.plaid.com',
    },
  },
}))

This changed nothing.
Would you be able to help me, tell me where to look or maybe share your experience? Thank you.

Suggestion from a colleague: "I noticed that you mention having your own Plaid wrapper class. Since it seems to be constructed with plaid = new Plaid(), there may be a separate PlaidApi that gets created within the constructor of Plaid that would be different from the plaidApiMock you create earlier in the test setup process. One suggestion may be to refactor so that the constructor of the Plaid wrapper class takes a PlaidApi as a parameter, and pass the plaidApiMock in for unit tests."
